# does a windows application in C# support gif annimation?

Tags: c#, gif, animated-gif

Is this possible ? if yes how ?  I am creating a windows application, which makes multiple web queries. I want the interface to have a loading symbol, so that the user doesn't feel that the screen has frozen. 
Thank you.

Comment: You need to run your code in a background thread to avoid blocking the UI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, I've already done it. Just use a PictureBox control, and set the gif image on it.

Comment: Here's a very simple example: http://www.megafileupload.com/en/file/219898/GifTest-zip.html
[]'s

Answer (score 1):

You should use the standard [progress bar control.](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/WorkingwithProgressBarinCSharp11302005045625AM/WorkingwithProgressBarinCSharp.aspx)